# Can we read and compare the value from the console in a single line?

Tags: java, console, java.util.scanner

Following is the piece of code i have used in c/c++ which is fairly simple:

```
while ((scanf_s("%d", &num) == 1)&&num>0)
```

Below is the usual java code to read input:

```
try(Scanner n1 = new Scanner(System.in))
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the  number of days");
        while(n1.hasNextInt())
        {
            days = n1.nextInt();
            //some stmts
            n1.nextLine();
        }
    }
```

How can use this while to read the input as well as compare the value in a single **"while"** like i can do in c and c++;

Comment: Why is so important to do this in a single line? There are many things that can be done in a single line, but when looking it from a readability perspective, it might be better to do it on two or more lines.

Comment: If you really want it on a single line, create a method and call it

Comment: @JorgeCampos: I havn't read that far, just started but still will try it out or sure

Comment: @hfontanez: I just wanted to optimize the code

Comment: Why do you think it's an optimization?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I think i used the wrong word there, what i meant was i want to shorten my code

Comment: Short doesn't mean better. You'd still have to invoke `n1.nextInt();` and you'd still have to assign the result to `days` (if you intend to use it). What you have is fine.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: So its better to use an if to compare the value. Well that settles it then thanks

Comment: An `if` to compare _what_ value?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: To compare whether the input is just an integer and not char or -ve integer or special character

Comment: @Dhananjay `hasNextInt` already tells you if there's an `int` waiting for you in the `Scanner`. You can use an `if` to check if it is positive after you've retrieved the value from the `Scanner` with `nextInt`, yes.

Comment: @Dhananjay you probably don't know about the rules for program optimization: *Rule #1:* Don't do it!  *Rule #2 (for experts only):* Don't do it yet!  Posting this question tells me you are not an expert, so you must obey rule #1 for program optimization.  Don't Do it.

Comment: @Dhananjay you replied to Sotirios "To compare whether the input is just an integer and not char or -ve integer or special character".  If you use `Scanner.nextInt()` it will throw an InputMismatchException if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range. Therefore, if you input anything but a valid value for an Integer (between `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE`), it will throw an exception; at which point you can handle the exception and move on. No need to write code to determine if the input is an integer.

Comment: @hfontanez: Thanks for the honest review. To be true, i was just trying for as many variations as possible, although minimizing code lines was my target but i now see, why its not. About Scanner.nextInt(), i read all that is to know, but i will keep trying the variations for better understanding. I want my base to be solid before i move on to higher level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could so something like this:

```
int num;
final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while (scanner.hasNextInt() && (num = scanner.nextInt()) > 0) {
  // do something with num
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives and error saying  cannot make a  static reference to the non static method

Comment: Can you post your complete code how you are calling it? You seem to be calling a non-static/instance method from a static context. Depending on your situation, you could make that method static if it does not depend on any instance variables.

Comment: Forget it, it was a silly mistake, i only used this statement while(scanner.hasNextInt() && (num = scanner.nextInt())) instead of while (scanner.hasNextInt() && (num = scanner.nextInt()) > 0). So its resolved

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could do something like this:

```
  int input;
  final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Type anything: ");
  try
  {
     input = scanner.nextInt();
     System.out.println("You typed: " + input);
  }
  catch (InputMismatchException e)
  {
     System.out.println("You typed a non-numeric value or the value entered is out of range.");
  }
```

You can handle the exception for cases where the input is not a number or out of range.

Comment: I haven't reached exception yet, but its starting tommorrow so yep, i will try this thanks